# Where is JP1 on the Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

Recently I have been attempting to make my Arduino Uno a PIC16F877A programmer. Looking at the schematic to do this, I see that there is no JP1 pin on the Arduino as specified on the diagram on the top-left.

[image]

As I am new to electrical engineering I may just be simply overlooking it yet this is unlikely because I have been puzzled by this for two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JP1 is not a pin. It is a connector, with, if my eyes still work, 2 pins, which look like 13 volt DC and Ground. Likewise JP2 is not a pin, but a connector, with, hmmm, 6 pins. Three of which go directly to the Arduino, another one to the Arduino via Q1, and a final pin to Ground.

Answer (score 1):

**None** of this is on the Arduino. You must construct **all** of this yourself.

Comment: I'm talking about the pins. If you notice to the left it says "Connections to arduino" and these pins do exist, for instance the A1 pin. Please do research before giving an answer.

Comment: Notice how the green box starts a bit above A1 and stops a bit below D4? Care to hazard a guess why?

Comment: Hint: JP1 is **not** a pin. It is a connector, with, if my eyes still work, 2 pins, which look like 13 volt DC and Ground. Likewise JP2 is not a pin, but a connector, with, hmmm, 6 pins. Three of which go directly to the Arduino, another one to the Arduino via Q1, and a final pin to Ground.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @dda. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.